# How can I disable autocorrect in Edge?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge, autocorrect

I want to disable autocorrect in specific page of Edge Browser.

How can I disable autocorrect in Edge? 
But I don't want to disable autocorrect of whole Windows10.
(example...Settings -> Devices -> Typing....This is not...!!)

Comment: I think StackOverflow isn't the place you want this type of question... Off Topic

Comment: Why do you think so? I don't understand.

Comment: It sounds for me linke a user Question and not programming related.

Answer (score 6):

You can solve this without editing the registry:

> It's not about Edge but the whole win 10. Open
>   Settings from the start menu, then go to devices. There you'll find a
>   tab named Typing, fifth in the list for me, and the autocorrect
>   feature is displayed there. If you switch the autocorrect off, edge
>   will stop bugging your text (i actually wrote this in edge ;) ).
>   Enjoy. :)

Note: Currently open Edge windows will still auto-(in)correct until Edge has been restarted.

Another article in the link in Etiennes answer.

Comment: Note that Edge windows need to be restarted before the settings have an effect.

Comment: I have pretty much everything disabled in windows 10 settings (including ShowAutoCorrection set to 1 and then set to inactive), from a really long time, but in edge I still get REALLY unwanted autocorrections like I want to type franciza (in my language) and I get corrected to francize … WITH NO WARNING WHATSOEVER !!!!!

Comment: I can also state categorically that this solution does not work.  I have set both 'Autocorrect misspelled words' and 'Highlight misspelled words' set to off.  Rebooted my laptop.  It still autocorrects words.

Comment: Update: I've read somewhere that this solution used to work but does not work anymore since the Anniversary update.

Comment: @THESorcerer I have found a slight work around to spell check activating on foreign languages. If you add the foreign language to your computer (Settings -> Time and Language -> Region and Language -> Add a Language), you can set your keyboard to this language by clicking on the language icon that will appear in the bottom right of the taskbar, or cycle through available languages via alt + shift. Spell check does not activate in Microsoft Edge for me as long as I type in the same language as activated for the keyboard. Sorry couldn't figure out a more thorough method to disable it.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently the menu is not available by default.

By reading the instructions here : http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/how-to-turn-of-autocorrect-typing-in-edge/6944dcc4-6ef4-4ec6-afaa-5a0ca08c3bd2?auth=1

> You can follow this and it should work :
>
> If for some reason the "Typing" tab in the settings is gone (It was for me) you can unhide it through regedit.
>
> Use regedit and search for the following value: "ShowAutoCorrection". Change the value to '1' and you should be able to access "Settings -> Devices -> Typing" to change your autocorrection settings.
>
> Restart your application, log in and out, or reboot your system to make the changes apparent. It worked for Skype at the very least for me.

Comment: Hey Crystal, did this help you doing what you wanted?

Comment: On the same page someone describes a way without editing the registry. I have been looking for this since ages, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

I have found a solution, friends of Edge! Download the Tampermonkey MS Edge extension from the Windows Store and install the following UserScript:

https://greasyfork.org/de/scripts/39190-disable-spellcheck-globally

This UserScript sets the "spellcheck" attribute to the global  element/tag of every website you visit so that Edge MUST obey the rules. This also fixes the issue of auto-correction.

If you want to limit it to a certain website just modify the "@include" tags, for example:

```
@include https://www.reddit.com/*
```

To disable spellchecking on reddit only.

You can get Tampermonkey here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/tampermonkey/9nblggh5162s

Works on Windows 10 build 17112.1

Comment: Thank you, this did work!  As opposed to the 'windows 10' setting above.

Answer (score 0):

What I found to do it disable autocorrect in the new Chromium-based Edge, is to right-click on a word that has been autocorrected. It should list the original word with the option to restore it. Beneath that, there should be an option to either disable autocorrect for that site or permanently. Select your preference and autocorrect should stop bugging you.
Hope to be of help.